# How to Draw Two Sheeted Hyperboloid with Geodesics

Tags: python, matlab, figure

I would like to recreate the image below (without the watermark) using either MATLAB or Python.

[This link](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/16688-how-to-draw-a-hyperboloid) was very helpful for drawing the hyperboloid but I haven't done anything beyond what is shown there. I need to keep the green geodesic curves. Can this be done easily?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check the [fimplicit3](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fimplicit3.html) function, given that you have the equation for the hyperboloid:

```
fimplicit3(@(x,y,z) x.^2 + y.^2 - z.^2 + 1)
```